# how to display complete array?

Tags: javascript

I am getting this **error:** [object Object],[object Object],[object Object].

I want to display complete array like this: **John Doe, Anna Smith, Peter Jones**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is not an error, just array of objects

Comment: you have to use ioop to got first name and last name inside that obj

Comment: If you’re looking for the inverse of this, see [How to return object of first and last names](/q/72356212/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

You coud use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and build a new array and join it later.

```js
var text = '{"employees":[' +
        '{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
        '{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
        '{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}',
    obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.employees.map(function (a) {
    return a. firstName + ' ' + a.lastName;
}).join(', ');
```

```html
<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

your array is an array of objects - you'll need to do some more coding to get it how you want it - consider using Array#map, then a Array#join to format the output as you want

```
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.employees.map(function(emp) {
    return emp.firstName + ' ' + emp.lastName;
}).join(', ');
```

> for ES2015 completeness

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.employees.map(emp => emp.firstName + ' ' + emp.lastName).join(', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the all names you can do like this,
If you want to load JSON from external file you have to keep JSON file on some where else on your system and you can load it using $.getJSON like below

```js
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';  //// keep this in an external file

$.getJSON('/path', function(data) {

   obj = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.employees.length; i++)
    {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += obj.employees[i].firstName + " " + obj.employees[i].lastName + ",";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: any idea if can do this from external file??

Comment: I have edit my answer with what you have ask you can load like that from external file, you have to pass the path what I have mentioned their

Comment: i have tried as you said but its not working this is [external](http://www.mybeautiful.net63.net/test/myTutorials-json.js) file

Comment: just add this and see '//mybeautiful.net63.net/test/myTutorials-json.js'

Comment: still not parsing

Comment: look at this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ for how to pass the url to .getJSON and their is lot of quetion and answer search and see in stack overflow

Comment: @Abubakar Anwar if you got the answer for your first question please make it as write answer